# get url component

Tags: php, html

My url is of the form `//blogs/1824#comment-203`

How do I get the final number 203 from the url?

Comment: i tried this few months back it is not possible in php right way, so i get url and explode it with # to reach to that value, lets for more answers

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The so called *fragment*, i.e. anything after `#`, is not send to the server.
It's only used client-side. You'd have to explicitly POST it to the server using Javascript.

That, BTW, is the reason Stackoverflow "double links" to individual posts:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848287/get-url-component/4848295#4848295
                                                                |       |
                                                     sent to server     |
                                                                        |
                                                           not sent to server,
                                                        only used by the browser
                                                           to scroll the page
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it via Javascript by looking at `window.location.hash`.

PHP can't access it directly; the URL hash (aka fragment) component is never sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$urlArray = parse_url($url);
echo $urlArray["fragment"];
```

Sorry but I think that the fragment is **not** sent to the server. You can't access it by having the URL, if you want to check more on the function, look on [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

**EDIT**: Got a typo saying the opposite